# Calculus Therom on Inverse Functions

Tags: calculus

[I understand this definition:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0oA.png)

[But I am not able to understand this definition and this definition is based upon the previous one, can anyone help and explain?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPTw.png)

Comment: Those aren't theorems. Those are definitions.

Comment: Sorry my bad ill edit the questions

Comment: The latter just says that $f^{-1}(x) = y$ means that $f(y) = x$. Nothing magical here. Just use the definition of inverse function.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I know it says that, but I am not able to depict the meaning behind

Comment: Get a piece of paper, and sketch a graph. Draw the line Y=X and flip the paper over that line. The result is the inverse of the original function. You may need to do this off the table so you can see through the paper. The result is often a relation, no a function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $f(x) = y$, we say that the function $f$ sends the object $x$ to $y.$ Simple enough, right? Now when we speak of inverse functions, the notation $f^{-1}(y) = x$ says that $y$ came from $x$. There's slightly more a formalism here (inverse image, pullback, blah blah blah), but let's keep this for now.

Now consider the relationship $f^{-1}(y) = x$. If we apply the function $f$ to both sides, we have

$$ f \left( f^{-1} (y) \right) = f(x) $$

but the left side is just $y$, as $f \circ f^{-1} = \operatorname{Id}$, or really $f(f^{-1} \left(x) \right) = x$. (A function undoes its inverse.)

What your text says is if you want to focus on the inverse function, i.e., if you wish to write $f^{-1} (x) = y$, you can instead write $f(y) = x$, just by applying $f$ on both sides.

Comment: Wow, that makes so much more sense. Thank you so much!